Does gluing two points prevent simple connectedness?
Let $X$ be any path-connected Hausdorff space and let $x,y\in X$ be distinct points. Let $X/(x\sim y)$ be the quotient space obtained by identifying $x$ and $y$. Is it possible for $X/(x\sim y)$ to be simply connected? It seems to me like it shouldn't be possible. Let $\gamma$ be a path from $x$ to $y$. Then $\gamma$ descends to a loop on $X/(x\sim y)$ and it seems to me like this loop should not be contractible. But I don't see any way to show that this loop is not contractible. Does anyone know a proof or counterexample?

Note that there is a double cover $Y'$ of $Y:=X/(x\sim y)$ given by
$$
Y' = \left(X\times\left\{0,1\right\}\right)/\left\{\left(x,0\right)\sim\left(y,1\right), \left(x,1\right)\sim\left(y,0\right)\right\}
$$
and the map $Y'\to Y$ is the one induced by the projection $X\times\left\{0,1\right\}\to X$.
(That it is a cover follows from Hausdorff-ness of $X$)
A loop in $Y$ that is induced from a path in $X$ from $x$ to $y$ would be lifted in $Y'$ to a path from $(x,0)$ to $(y,0)\sim (x,1)$; however any contractible loop in $Y$ would be lifted to a closed loop in $Y'$.
Therefore $Y$ is not simply-connected

Very nice. I was thinking of an infinite cyclic cover until I saw this, which is more elegant.

@LeeMosher Well the infinite cyclic cover can be built similarly as $(X\times\mathbb{Z})/\left{(x,k)\sim(y,k+1) : k\in\mathbb{Z}\right}$

Thank you! This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for.

Here's another partial answer giving some sufficient conditions for this to hold. My personal hunch is that the statement is false (Hausdorffness seems too weak a condition to say much about a homotopy theoretic problem), but I've tried for a while and haven't been able to come up with a counterexample, and this answer should also serve to illustrate why this might be somewhat difficult.

Let's prove the following:

Proposition: If $X$ is a path-connected, well-pointed Hausdorff space and $x, y \in X$ are two distinct points, then $Y := X / \{x, y\}$ is not simply connected.

Proof: Using that $X$ is Hausdorff and well-pointed, we see that the inclusion $\{x, y\} \hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration. Thus, we have a long exact sequence
$$
    \cdots \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_1(\{x, y\})}_{= 0} \to \tilde{H}_1(X) \to \tilde{H}_1(Y) \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_0(\{x, y\})}_{\cong \mathbb{Z}} \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_0(X)}_{= 0} \to \underbrace{\tilde{H}_0(Y)}_{= 0} \to 0 
$$
in reduced ordinary homology, hence a short exact sequence
$$
    0 \to \tilde{H}_1(X) \to \tilde{H}_1(Y) \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$
and therefore a splitting $\tilde{H}_1(Y) \cong \tilde{H}_1(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. In particular $\pi_1(Y)^\mathrm{ab} \cong \tilde{H}_1(Y)$ is nonzero, and therefore so is $\pi_1(Y)$. $\Box$

Note that this calculation agrees nicely with the heuristic in Qiaochu Yuan's answer.
Of course, pretty much any "reasonable" space (from the algebraic topologist's point of view) is well-pointed (in particular all CW-complexes and all manifolds are), so a counterexample has to be somewhat "nasty," and computing invariants of nasty spaces is often somewhat difficult.

This is a very nice solution! I can appreciate the method of cofibrations. It's worth mentioning that another user was able to show that the statement is true for arbitrary path-connected Hausdorff spaces by constructing a covering space.

Under mild hypotheses, this quotient is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of $X$ and a circle (consider stretching a "noodle" between $x$ and $y$, then deforming this noodle along a path from $x$ to $y$), so its fundamental group is the free product of $\pi_1(X)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

Do you know what hypotheses are needed to make this argument work?

@Anon I believe you need something like existence of a path $G$ (as in, a subspace homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$) between $x$ and $y$ in $X$ such that the inclusion $G \hookrightarrow X$ has the homotopy extension property. Whether this is a "mild" condition is up for debate, but it does hold in pretty much all spaces algebraic topologists care about (all manifolds, all CW-complexes, all simplicial complexes, ...).

If we need additional hypotheses what is then a counterexample without additional hypotheses?

@psl2Z I'm sure if anybody knew they'd have answered.

Respectfully, this answer would seriously benefit from elaboration. I have the visual image, but rigorously stating anything is hard for me here. Which hypotheses?
